# How do you load multiple components/ vue pages at the same time with vue-router?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

Is there a way to load more than one component at the same when loading a page with vue router ?
I have looked into the documentation and there is a example their site with a working example with one issue , you need to actually click on the "/" link to load the vue
here is the link to that example [Vue-Router Names Views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html)
I am using Laravel and vue is inside the Laravel , a blade page with `<router-view>` will load the front page

here is my router code

```
// Pages front
import Home from "../pages/front/Home.vue";
import Login from "../pages/front/Login.vue";
import Test from "../components/test.vue"
// Pages back
import Dashboard from "../pages/back/Dashboard.vue";


Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        components: {
            default: Home,
            helper: Test
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: "/login",
                name: "login",
                component: Login
            }
        ]
    }, {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "dashbaord",
        components: Dashboard
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({mode: "history", base: process.env.BASE_URL, routes});

export default router;
```

and here is my home page with 2 `<router-view>`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <navigationTop />
    <h1 class="text-xl">Home Page</h1>
    <router-view />
    <router-view name="helper" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import navigationTop from "../../components/ExampleComponent";
export default {
  name: "",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  components: {
    navigationTop,
  },
  computed: {},
  mounted: () => {},
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

so i am trying to load the `Test` page as soon as my home page is loaded and use the other `<router-view>` to load other pages .

Comment: Is it possible any of Home's child routes would need to change the `helper` component to something other than `Test`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've defined your named view at the top level (eg `App.vue`) but you're trying to use the *helper* view within your `Home` component.

Given the layout you're trying to achieve, I don't think you actually want to use named views. To make `Test` a permanent fixture for the *home* route, this seems to be more what you'd be after in `Home.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NavigationTop />
    <h1 class="text-xl">Home Page</h1>
    <router-view />
    <Test /> <!--  directly inject Test here -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import NavigationTop from "@/components/ExampleComponent";
import Test from "@/components/test.vue";

export default {
  name: "",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  components: {
    NavigationTop,
    Test
  },
  computed: {},
  mounted: () => {},
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: but then TEST will be shown on all pages which is not what i want

Comment: @CYBERSIX your example code needs more examples then. Please also see my question on your comment above

Comment: All I am trying to achieve is to when Home is loading , test also be loaded without needing to click on any link or anything ... it may not even be possible. can you or can you not load more than one component at the same with vue-router ??? thanks

Comment: It's not clear what result you want. Could you please edit your question to elaborate